# Database schema with a column containing a link to a local file

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I need a database that can contain a person's name, sex, IdNum and photograph. The first three parameters are very easy but the third one: photograph, is a bit challenging for me. I want a command such that it can store a link to wherever the photograph is on the user's file system instead of using the BLOB  data type. I just need advice on how best to do this. Think of a form where the user has to enter his/her IdNum and all other information is displayed on the screen. Their name, sex, IdNum and photograph. Something along that line.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Store the photo on the file system and stash its path name into a varchar or other textual field.

Comment: but it is easier if itz on your own file system. How about taking it to the web where the user wants to insert their pix into an online form that will store the info in the table?

Answer (score 0):

A link is nothing else than a String. So use the VARCHAR-type and you're good to go.

Maybe you should improve your question.